# use mockito to stub final method

Tags: java, mockito, final, powermock

I need to use a mock who has a final method.
So i use powermock but it does not work

```
class B {
    public final int nb() {
        return 4;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
public class Exemple extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void test() { 
        B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);

        PowerMockito.when(b.nb()).thenReturn(5);

        final int actualState = b.nb();

        assertEquals(5, actualState);

    }   
}
```

if someone has a solution,
thank you in advance

Comment: Why this not work for you, this is working very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is fine, should work without any problem.

```
Tests Passed: 1 passed in 0,226 s
```

I have tested it with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it works, my buildpath was not good,

Thank you for your help