# How to get original class name from a mocking object?

Tags: java, mockito

```
Book aBook = mock(Book.class);
```

when I write to execute

`aBook.getClass()` it gives

```
classcom.tw.model.Book$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$feb29207
```

But I want : `classcom.tw.model.Book`

Comment: `aBook.getClass().getSuperclass()` (or one of the classes in `.getInterfaces()`, if the mocked class is an interface).

Comment: But why do you actually need to know such information? By and large, if you need to know the actual class of an instance, your design has have problems.

Comment: `doAnswer(...).when(...)`?

Comment: @Pelocho : `getClass` is final, though. Could be tricky.

Comment: Can you use instanceof instead of getClass?

Comment: when(aBook.getClass()).thenReturn(aBook.getClass().getSuperclass());
I tried this but got error

Comment: `getClass` is final.

Comment: how can i stub getClass() then

Comment: Search for "stub final method java" if you really want to go that route instead of @Absurd-Mind's suggestion. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking)

Comment: Maybe trying with [PowerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092935/use-mockito-to-stub-final-method)?

Answer (score 2):

Since Mockito 2.1.0 you can use `getMockCreationSettings()` to get details on **what** was mocked. from the [docs](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-mockito-2)

> Added the possibility to access the mock creation settings via
>
> `Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getMockCreationSettings()`

Here's an example:

```
@Test
public void aTest() {
    Foo mock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

    MockCreationSettings<?> mockCreationSettings = Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getMockCreationSettings();

    Assert.assertEquals(Foo.class, mockCreationSettings.getTypeToMock());
}
```

Comment: From the comments I assumed OP is calling getClass inside the method under test. This approach doesn't satisfy OPs problem then.

Comment: The OP didn't clarify **where** he wants to call `aBook.getClass()` so I don't think it is clear yet (to me, at least :) exactly where/when/how he wants to get the original type for his mock, if he wants to get it _within_ the test case then this answer will work but if he needs to get it inside the system-under-test then it won't.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have added an answer for the other case ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `instanceof` instead of `getClass()`

```
void methodUnderTest(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Book) {
        Book book = (Book) object;
        // read the book
    }
}
```

this can now easily be tested with a mock:

```
@Test
public void bookTest() {
    methodUnderTest(mock(Book.class));
}
```